# How to hide keyboard on return key in Sprite kit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, keyboard, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I'm using UITextField for user to enter his name. And this is how I add UITextField to the game.

```
let firstPlayer:UITextField = UITextField()
firstPlayer.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: (self.scene?.size.width)! * 0.21, y: (self.scene?.size.height)! * 0.2), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
firstPlayer.placeholder = "First Player Name"
firstPlayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
firstPlayer.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
firstPlayer.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
firstPlayer.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.default
firstPlayer.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
firstPlayer.isHidden = true
view.addSubview(firstPlayer)
```

later i unhide the textfield before it's needed. when I press on textfield in simulator the keyboard pops up. But when I press Return nothing happens.

I searched about this for sprite kit but found everything about uikit. I tried adding

```
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      self.view.endEditing(true);   // or resignFirstResponder
      return false;
    }
```

to the GameViewController or in it's viewDidLoad or willLayoutSubviews but nothing worked.
I can't understand how it would be done in sprite kit.

Any Help will be really Appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Is `textFieldShouldReturn` even being called?

Comment: @rmaddy yes that's what I didn't understand how can I call it in sprite kit we can't use node touched or anything like that

Comment: I don't think you answered my question. If you put a breakpoint inside `textFieldShouldReturn` and then tap the return key, is `textFieldShouldReturn` stopping at the breakpoint? Yes or no?

Comment: @rmaddy no it doesn't Prints anything

Comment: so textFieldShouldReturn is the method for dismissing keyboard in sprite kit?

Comment: if it is where should I add that method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
firstPlayer.delegate = self as? UITextFieldDelegate
```

should just be:

```
firstPlayer.delegate = self
```

The fact that you added the `as? UITextFieldDelegate` probably means that you forgot to indicate that your class conforms to `UITextFieldDelegate`.

Update your class declaration from something like:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
```

to something like:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

Just add the `, UITextFieldDelegate` to whatever your current declaration is.

You also have a typo on:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
```

That needs to be:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
```

Note the space after the `_`.

Comment: previously when I try to make delegate as self it used to give me this error Cannot assign value of type 'HomeScene' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?'

Comment: Yes, that's what the second change in my answer resolves. Read my entire answer and make all three changes.

Comment: but after adding delegate to the class now it doesn't gives me that error, But it still doesn't hides the keyboard

Comment: Did you also fix the third mistake I pointed out in my answer?

Comment: Also make sure that `textFieldShouldReturn` is a top-level method of the class, not inside any other method.

Comment: thanks man it's working perfectly fine now, I had added it to view controller previously that's why it wasn't working even now. Your life saver keep up the good work :)